# JS - What is the difference here?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm a newbie to JS and it would be extremely useful to know what the differenece is between the following two if statement conditions...

First condition (not actually working):

```
if ( window.location.pathname == '/#register' ) {

// Code

}
```

Second condition:

```
if (document.URL.indexOf("#register") >= 0) {

// Code...

}
```

FYI, this would help me solve a bug I'm experiencing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606428/smooth-scroll-buggy-with-a-partial-view)

Comment: Have you tried `console.log( window.location.pathname )` to see what the value actually is?

Comment: I have now ;) it says it's just `/`

Comment: Well, there's your problem. It seems you actually want `window.location.hash`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first checks for an exact match. And it does it on the pathname, which doesn't include the hash, so it probably doesn't do what you want.

The second one checks the string contains `"#register"`, so the full path could be bigger, like `/#register_or_not` or `/some/other/path#register`

Probably your best option would be to do a regex pattern match on the URL, to ensure that the hash it matches is ONLY 'register', while allowing the rest of the URL to be whatever:

```
if (document.URL.match(/.*#register$/)) {
```

Comment: Or more likely `/some/other/path#register`

Comment: @StevenMoseley It's CW, don't hesitate to edit to make it better.

Comment: The main problem is that `window.location.pathname` doesn't include the hash.

Comment: Although I didn't go with this, I felt that this answered the question best. Can see the live, fixed version of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606428/smooth-scroll-buggy-with-a-partial-view/16735053) at https://www.tradechase.com

Answer (score 2):

The second just check if the url contains #register, the first the url path, you can do it also with location.hash

```
if(location.hash=='#register') { //....
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the method I used. It fixes [this bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606428/smooth-scroll-buggy-with-a-partial-view/16735053) which is now live at https://www.tradechase.com

Answer (score 1):

The first one performs an exact match between `window.location.pathname` and `/#register`. The second one looks for `#register` anywhere in `document.URL`.

Answer (score 1):

This if block check the strings whether they are equal or not

```
if ( window.location.pathname == '/#register' ) {

 // Code

}
```

The indexOf() method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string.

This method returns -1 if the value to search for never occurs.

```
if (document.URL.indexOf("#register") >= 0) {

   // Code...

}
```